# Hibernate. Property not found on type

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp

I have entity class Publication. It connected with entity class Teacher as ManyToMany.

Here's part of Publication class

```
// create connectivity with table Teacher
public Set<Teacher> teachers;

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "Bridge2",
           joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "PublicationId"),
           inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "TeacherId"))
public Set<Teacher> getTeacher() {
    return teachers;
}

public void setTeacher(Set<Teacher> teachers) {
    this.teachers = teachers;
}
```

I select publication from database and pass it to JSP page. At JSP page I try to view all teachers but always get exception **Property 'teachers' not found on type org.irs.entities.Publication.**

Here's part of JSP file

```
<td> <!-- view all teachers -->
    <c:forEach var="t" items="${publication.teachers}">
        ${t.teacherFullName}<br/>
    </c:forEach>
</td>
```

If anyone knows the reason of this problem, I'll be gratful for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try renaming your accessor methods to `getTeachers` and `setTeachers` (plural instead of singular).

Hibernate sees `getTeacher`, so the property name is `teacher`. You are trying to to access the property `teachers` instead.

Answer (score 2):

It seems it's because of your `getter` and `setter` are `teacher` rather than `teachers`. Hibernate regards `setter` and `getters` rather than fields. Changing them to setTeacher**s** and getTeacher**s** may resolve problem.